# Netlify Integration with planetScale acting weird

Tags: next.js, prisma, netlify

I am creating a NextJS project using prisma and planetScale database. Everything works on localhost, but not on netlify. The database connection works, I can log in and log out. In the admin menu you can create new posts and list them. The problem is the following:

Listing is like caching and even if I delete items from the database, they are still listed on the page. If I log out and back in it will be fine, but on localhost it immediately disappears from there too.
The other (and bigger) problem is that in production the create function runs to 404, even though localhost works flawlessly.
I do not understand the reason for the 404, because all other routes work perfectly.
For now, I am using the same database on local and in production that I created on planetScale.

Here is the code of the create function:

```
'use client'

async function onSubmit(event:) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const formData = new FormData(event.target);
        const form = Object.fromEntries(formData);
        const response = await createHowItsMade(form)
        if (!response) {
            toast.error("Could not save!")
            return
        }
        toast.success("Saved successfully")
        push("/admin/how-its-made")
    }
```

```
'use server'

export async function createHowItsMade (data): Promise<boolean> {
    try {
      await prisma.howItsMade.create({
        data: {
          title: data.title,
          position: parseInt(data.position),
          description: data.description,
        }
      })
      revalidatePath("/admin/how-its-made")
      return true
    } catch (error) {
      return false
    }
  }
```

Any help would be much appreciated since I have no clue where to start.